# Selenium python how to find button by full match

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

this (Selenium python) function clicking on Follow buttons, but also clicking on Following buttons (because Following also contains Follow). How to prevent it? I need full match (Follow only). thank you

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Follow')]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below **xpath**.The first one give you exact match and then second one truncate the space if they have.

```
//button[text()='Follow']
```

OR

```
//button[normalize-space(.)='Follow']
```

**Code**:

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[text()='Follow']")
```